# Can I implement multiple module types with 1 module?

Tags: module, constraints, ocaml, reason

Given these module types:

```ml
module type CodecTypes = {
  type t;
  type token;
};

module type Decode = {
  include CodecTypes;
  let decode: BsGenericParser.Parse.parser(token, t);
};

module type Encode = {
  include CodecTypes;
  let encode: t => list(token);
};
```

Is there a way to share the abstract types `t` and `token` between the two module types? 
I tried:

```ml
module type Codec = {
  include Encode;
  include Decode;
}
```

but the compiler complains about name clashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed you can, using [signature constraints](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/modtypes.html#ss:mty-with) with [destructive substitution](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.10/htmlman/signaturesubstitution.html):

```ml
module type Codec = {
  include Encode;
  include Decode with type t := t and type token := token;
}
```

Note that you can also write signature constraints with `=` instead of`:=`, but this will yield the same error. The difference between them is that `=` is a type equality that require the type on both sides to be equal, and `:=` will replace ("destructively substitute") the type on the left-hand side. In this case that means `Decode.t` is replaced by `Encode.t`.

To better illustrate this, consider this example:

```ml
module type Codec = {
  type u;
  include Encode with type t := u;
  include Decode with type t := u and type token := token;
}
```

which will result in the following module type:

```ml
module type Codec = {
  type u;
  type token;
  let encode: u => list(token);
  let decode: list(token) => u;
};
```

where `t` no longer occurs at all, having been replaced by `u` instead.

Comment: I have no idea. See the note I just added at the end. I'm hoping our resident documentation guru will either know where it is and/or fix it if necessary.

Comment: Well. At least it’s documented _here_ now . Thanks!

Comment: Like often, if this is not documented in the technical reference part of the manual, this means that the documentation is in the extension chapter: https://ocaml.org/releases/4.10/htmlman/signaturesubstitution.html .

Comment: Thanks @octachron. That's a good explanation too. I think one reason it's hard to find is that it uses the term "signature constraint", while the core language calls it a "module constraint" (although it also mentions "constrained signature"). This makes it more difficult to find through search.

Comment: Would be nice to have the ocaml manual completely translated into Reason for those who never touched ocaml before.